# Is there a way to use for-each function in vectors as it is used in Lists in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

In scheme when working with Lists, one can easily use `for-each`. I have used it in the following code.

```
(for-each (lambda (arg)
          (diplayln arg)
```

and the output is

```
1

2

3

4
```

I want to use the same analogy for vectors, am implementing a function `vector-for-each`

such that `(vector-for-each display (vector "red" "orange"))`. The output should be `"red" "orange"`.

What is the best way of implementing `for-each` for vectors in scheme?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the _exact_ output you're expecting for the sample input you provided: `(vector "red" "orange")`

Comment: `vector-for-each` is a standard (r6rs) [Scheme](http://scheme.com/tspl4/control.html#./control:s47) form. If defining it yourself, start with `(define (vector-for-each proc vec)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick in Racket:

```
(for ([color (vector "red" "orange")])
  (display (string-append "\"" color "\"")) ; or use `displayln`
  (newline))
```

I'd rather use `printf`, but if you want to use `display` it's fine. This is how I'd do it:

```
(for ([color (vector "red" "orange")])
  (printf "~s~n" color))
```

Comment: Thanks it works with display but it does return the output with strings like "red" "orange"

Comment: @MugoyaDihfahsih I don't get your comment, what was the output and what were you expecting? why is it wrong, and can it be fixed by changing the string in `printf`? Or maybe use `displayln` instead?

Comment: I have updated the question, essentially what i want is to use display and out put strings like this "red" "oranges" with double quotes

Comment: @MugoyaDihfahsih ok, so you want to display the quotes. We need to add them explicitly, they're removed when displayed. I've updated my solution.

Comment: how do i include the quotes when i use display instead of printf

Comment: @MugoyaDihfahsih it's already in my answer, you need to create a new string using `string-append` and add the quotes at both ends, escaping them like `"\""`. More reasons to avoid using `display`...

Comment: @MugoyaDihfahsih you should ask yourself why do you want to print the quotes in the first place, they're _not_ part of the string, adding them creates unnecessary hassle as you can see.

Answer (score 2):

`vector-for-each` can be defined in Racket:

```
#lang racket

(define (vector-for-each proc vec) ;; (X -> ) VectorOfX ->
  ;; apply proc to elements of vec in order
  (do ([i 0 (add1 i)])
    ((= i (vector-length vec)))
    (proc (vector-ref vec i))))

(vector-for-each displayln '#(1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Racket comes with an implementation of the [SRFI-43 vector library](https://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-43.html), which includes `vector-for-each`:

```lisp
> (require srfi/43)
> (vector-for-each (lambda (i n) (displayln n)) (vector 1 2 3))
1
2
3
```

(This version uses a function that takes two arguments - the index of the current element, and the element itself. Or more arguments if called with multiple vectors.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`writeln`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmisc..rkt%29._writeln%29%29) (or [`printf`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._printf%29%29) with `~s`):

```
> (for ([color (vector "red" "orange")])
    (writeln color))
"red"
"orange"

> (for ([color (vector "red" "orange")])
    (printf "~s~n" color))
"red"
"orange"
```